# js file is not getting loaded while serving html from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to serve the index.html file from the node server, but I am getting this error "localhost/:1 Refused to execute the script from 'http://localhost:3001/assets/app.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Common JS Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CommonJS</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets")));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./index.html"))
})

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3001!'))
```

app.js

```
console.log('hiiii')
```

Comment: Sorry I know its a very naive question, but I have recently started working on nodeJS

Answer (score 2):

"assets" is the static path, so modify the script src to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```

and it should work

Explanation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: yes it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: of course. The ExpressJS documentation edit above explains why